# Properties of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(V,\,\oplus,\,\odot)$ be a vector space. Let $u\in V$ and let $v$ be the additive inverse of $u$.

$(i)$ Prove that $0\odot u = 0_{V}$.

$(ii)$ Prove that $(-1)\odot u = v$.

Note: $0_{V}$ denotes the zero vector of $V$.

---

Now for $(i)$: Suppose $u\in V$, then \begin{align}0\odot u &= (v - v)\odot u & \text{By the $-$ operation in $V$.}\\ &= (v\odot u) \oplus (- (v\odot u)) & \text{By the distributivityof vectors in $V$.}\\ &= 0_{V} \oplus 0_{V} = 0_{V}.& \text{By the definition of $\oplus$.}\end{align}

Is this correct?

---

For $(ii)$ I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: No, it's not correct $\odot$ denotes `scalar` multiplication, and $v-v$ is not a scalar (btw, what is the base field?)

Comment: I guess that $\odot$ denotes the scalar mulitplication. In your attempt to $(i)$, there are some correct ideas, but also some confusions. Since $\odot$ is the scalar multiplication, you are not allowed to write $v \odot u$ where $v,u$ are vectors. You can only write $\lambda \odot u$ where $\lambda$ is a scalar from the underlying field and $u$ is a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would go like this:

1. Prove that $0_V$ is unique. (That is, assume there exist two neutral elements for $\oplus$ and conclude that they're equal) Then, with this in mind, prove that $0\odot u$ behaves just like $0_V$ and, therefore, they should be equal.
2. Prove that the additive inverse of a given element is unique and, as in $(i)$, prove that $(-1)\cdot u$ behaves like the additive inverse of $u$ (i.e. $u \oplus \left((-1)\odot u \right) = 0_V$). For this part, using $(i)$ would help.

Answer (score 2):

For the point $(ii)$ we have $$u +[ (-1) \odot u] = [(1) \odot u]+[(-1) \odot u] = (1-1)\odot u = 0 \odot u = 0_V$$ This means that $(-1) \odot u = v$.

Answer (score 1):

For point $(i)$:

$$u=1\odot u=(1+0)\odot u=1\odot u+ 0\odot u=u+ 0\odot u$$
hence $\,\,0\odot u=0.$

Comment: Don't you mean $0\odot u = 0$?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for pointing the typo!